# Debouncing : Can we use only one capacitor for multiple Key?

Tags: circuit-design

In my project, I've to use more than 5 keys to be interfaced with Micro-controller. We can use sufficiently large capacitor to reduce debouncing of key. My question is: can I use one single capacitor for all the five keys or should I use separate capacitors for each key.

if No, what would happen we try to use one capacitor for all keys.

Comment: Have you considered doing the debouncing in software, then you need zero capacitors?

Comment: No, I haven't considered it yet. I'll go though it.

Answer (score 1):

If you connect each button to a different MCU pin, then you must have a capacitor for each button.

You can also connect all buttons to a [resistive ladder and use MCU ADC to sample the voltage](http://tronixstuff.com/2011/01/11/tutorial-using-analog-input-for-multiple-buttons/), bounce is not a problem then, because of low speed of the ADC.

My preferred solution: don't debounce, just lower the sampling rate. Eg. have a timer interrupt between 10-100Hz and sample buttons in the main loop only when the interrupt handler sets a flag.

Comment: You may want to state what happens if you _don't_ use a different capacitor for each MCU pin - crosstalk, or phantom presses, or what-have-you.